# Queries on knapsack

Tags: dynamic-programming, matrices, intervals

Given items with weights $w_{1}, w_{2}, \dots, w_{n}$ and queries of form $(l, r, w)$ asking for possibility to find a subset of items $w_{l}, w_{l + 1}, \dots, w_{r}$ with total weight $w$, how to answer these queries with $O(1)$ time by having done precalculation of some table in $O(nW)$ time, where W is strict upper bound for $w_{i}$.

The time for precalculation looks similar to the straight 0-1 knapsack, but here I can't see what we really should put in the table.

Comment: Are you sure $W$ is the upper bound for $w_i$, rather than $\sum w_i$?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that $W$ is an integer upper bound to $\sum_i w_i$, as asked by xskxzr, that all $w_i$ are positive integers, and that the values $w$ in the queries are also integers upper bounded by $W$.

For $i \ge 1$, let $S[i,w]$ be the largest index $j \in \{1, \dots, i\}$ such that it is possible to select a subset of $\{w_k : j \le k \le i  \}$ of weight $w>0$. If no such index $j$ exists, or if $w \le 0$, let $S[i,w] = -\infty$.

According to the above definition:

- For $w \neq w_1$, $S[1,w] = - \infty$.
- For $i \ge 1$, $S[i,w_i] = i$.
- For $i>1$, and $w \neq w_i$, $S[i,w] = \max 
  \begin{cases}
  S[i-1,w] & \\
  S[i-1,w-w_i] &
  \end{cases}
  $

There are only $O(n W$) "interesting" values of $S[i,w]$ to compute (namely those with $i=1,\dots,n$ and $w=1,\dots,W$), each of which can be found in constant time.

To answer a query $(l,r,w)$ proceed as follows (pick the first condition that applies):

- If $w = 0$, return true (the subset you're looking for is the empty set);
- If $w < 0$, return false;
- If $r < 1$, return false (since, at this point, $w \neq 0$).
- return true if and only if $S[\min\{r,n\},w] \ge l$.